# Can I know with PHP that the Facebook LIKE Button is pressed?

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-likebox

Can I know with PHP that the Facebook LIKE Button is pressed?
At the same time when the LIKE Button is pressed, I'd like to run the PHP code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd need to use [`FB.Event.subscribe`](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.Event.subscribe/) for the (rather absurdly named) `edge.create` event to fire an AJAX call to your server.

Comment: Thank you! ! Your opinion has been great help to me.